# How to keep datarow data?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

```
 DataRow temptDataRow = dtable.NewRow();
 temptDataRow = dtable.Rows[selectSeq];
 temptDataRow.AcceptChanges();
 dtable.Rows[selectSeq].Delete();
 dtable.AcceptChanges();
```

When you delete a row of a datatable referenced by datarow data, it is blown. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Isn't that what you would expect when you actively delete a row? Under which circumstance would you not want to have the row deleted that you just deleted?

Comment: Is there a way to store the data I'm referencing separately?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Let me know if I misunderstood and I will try to change it.